# Social Network Script to wrap existing PHP website

Tags: php, social-networking, elgg

I have a small existing PHP site that I would like to integrate with a social network software.  Essentially, adding my 3-4 pages inside an existing social networking site for functionality such as user management, groups, and friending.  I have looked at Dolphin, Pligg, and Elgg but am struggling to find something that I can integrate with my existing pages. Is there something else that would allow me to add code to my existing php pages to display login info, widgets etc?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an existing CMS such as [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) would meet your needs?

To add social network abilities to Joomla you could look at [Jomsocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/) or [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/).